# Can't get past a Django ImportError after running manage.py sync.db

Tags: python, django

Very new to coding. I've been trying to install this tablestacker: http://datadesk.github.io/latimes-table-stacker/
And I'm running into problems with manage.py syncdb, and I can't get past this particular error. My hunch is: I have both Python 2.6 and 2.7 on my computer, and I'm not sure how to make sure everything's running with 2.7. I have a feeling things are being installed for 2.6.

Any advice is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import django.template.loaders.app_directories
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 23, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError bakery: No module named bakery
```

Comment: Looks like it is choking on a missing "bakery" import. Is there a module named bakery?

Comment: Thanks, I made an alias for pip2.7, and wrote pip-2.7 install instead of pip install, and it went through with the sync this time. Of course, now there are "migration" errors, so that's up next. It says "Not synced (use migrations): - table_stacker
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: does bakery have `__init__.py` ?

Comment: `migrations` are usually handled by South. Check http://south.aeracode.org/ docs. Usually python manage.py migrate should do it, but you should understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I did import south, used python manage.py migrate, and created aliases for all python2.7 commands like pip and easy_install so to be sure I'm not using 2.6.